# ListBox Add Item

Tags: vb6

Can someone help me? How to display the medicines in listbox if the stock quantity is less than 15 ?

I tried this code but it's not working.

```
Private Sub List1_Click()
If Text3.Text <= 15 And Text3.Text > 1 Then List1.AddItem Adodc1.Recordset("MedicineName")
end sub
```

Seems my code is wrong. I don't know what to do next. Please help

Here is my code in **datagrid** :

```
Private Sub DataGrid2_Click()
With frm_ScrollUP1

 .Text3.Text = Adodc2.Recordset.Fields("StockQuantity")
  .Combo1.Text = Adodc2.Recordset.Fields("medicinename")
If Text3.Text < 0 Then
MsgBox Combo1 & " stock is not enough for the quantity you need!", vbExclamation, "   SORRY..."
Text3.Text = ""
Exit Sub
End If

If Text3.Text <= 15 And Text3.Text > 1 Then
MsgBox "Please add more stocks of " & Combo1 & " !", vbExclamation, "   Warning!"
ElseIf Text3.Text = 0 Then
MsgBox Combo1 & " is Empty!", vbCritical, "   Warning!"
End If


Combo1 = "Medicine Brand"
Text2.Text = ""
Text3.Text = ""
Combo2 = "---MMMM----"
Combo3 = "-DD-"
Combo4 = "---YYYY---"
Text2.Enabled = False
End With

end sub
```

Comment: Just to clarify you said to display item in listbox if it is less than 15 but your code is less than or *equal* to 15.  Did you try stepping through your code?

Answer (score 0):

when comparing `Text` with number, its best to convert the string to the number:

```
If Val(Text3.Text) <= 15 And Val(Text3.Text) > 1 Then List1.AddItem Adodc1.Recordset("MedicineName")
```